# Error of "error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied" occurs while installing Carthage

Tags: macos, homebrew, carthage

I want to install carthage on my Mac OS using `brew install carthage` command. However, I get the following error:

```
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
touch: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
Warning: carthage 0.26.2 is already installed, it's just not linked.
You can use `brew link carthage` to link this version.
```

I also get the following error when I used `sudo brew install carthage`:

```
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
```

Can you let me know what is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please run `brew doctor`; follow its recommendations; and try again.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Check for the permissions on these files.

```
ls -l /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/FETCH_HEAD
ls -l /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask/.git/FETCH_HEAD
ls -l /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/.git/FETCH_HEAD
ls -l /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/.git/FETCH_HEAD
```

If you don't have the permissions, run

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* && sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*
```

In High Sierra and above, Run this command instead:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

You can also see the related github issues [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/43471)

Comment: `Operation not permitted`

Comment: Under macOS Mojave (10.14) I needed to run this: `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* && sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*`

Comment: had same issue, this worked quite well for me thank you @Kazunori Takaishi

Comment: sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
Works like charm.

Answer (score 83):

In High Sierra, run the command:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me :
macOS Catalina 10.15.1

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* && sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this command may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Answer (score 15):

In my case this command working:

```
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

However, there is also an easier way of installing Carthage instead of commands line way. It is enough to download the latest package from this link and install it in a wizard way on you Mac.

https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases

Comment: @doapydave: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this also instead
`sudo chown -R $USER $(brew --prefix)/*`

Answer (score 2):

I have macOS Catalina 10.15.1 after hours (like always) this worked.

`sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* && sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*`

Answer (score 1):

I have High Sierra and only this worked for me.

```
1. sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/* && sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/*
you should not write sudo before brew the right command is 
2. brew install mysql
```